# How to display the selected data in those fields php?

Tags: php, sql, oracle, web

I  wrote the following code. It works when the primary key is integer. However when the primary key is String (which is what I need) it does not display the selected data in those fields. this is the code:

```
include("connection.php");
$equipId=$_GET["equipment_id"];
$conn = oci_connect($dbuname, $dbpwd,$db) or die("DB connection unsuccessful!");
$query= "SELECT * FROM EQUIPMENT WHERE EQUIPMENT_ID =".$_GET["equipment_id"];**
```

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Can questions be closed on the grounds of "Bobby Tables" yet?

Comment: What CD001 means is, you're [vulnerable to SQL Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).  Fix it, or lose (or worse, leak) your database.

Comment: Hi am using SQL oracle, does this still apply ?

Answer (score 0):

When writing a query all strings must be encased in quotes, you may use single or double quotes.

$query= "SELECT * FROM EQUIPMENT WHERE EQUIPMENT_ID ='".$_GET["equipment_id"]."'";

Comment: hi, 
this did not solved the problem. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

```
$query= "SELECT * FROM EQUIPMENT WHERE EQUIPMENT_ID ='".$_GET["equipment_id"] . "'";
```

Proper answer:
please escape your inputs. I don't know that particular library you are using but I would advice using PDO or MySQLi

Here is s link that should be helpful:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php